# Animation going too fast. Can't seem to slow down

Tags: ios, swift

My animations are going too fast. I'm doing a pattern matching game and I have 4 UIViews with different colors. I want one to blink and then about a second later, have another UIView blink. The views are blinking by my tag identifier which I already set differently for each view (1,2,3,4). It seems like they are all going at the same time. I've already tried adjusting the values for the animateWithDuration function and that doesn't seem to help.

Here is my print output so you can see it's executing in the right order...

```
gary
3
gary
2
gary
2
gary
3
gary
2



func beginGame() {
    var level = 5

    for _ in 1...level {
        self.randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)) + 1
        let originalColor:UIColor = self.view.viewWithTag(randomNumber)!.backgroundColor!
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {


            self.view.viewWithTag(self.randomNumber)!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
              self.view.viewWithTag(self.randomNumber)!.backgroundColor = originalColor

            print("gary")


            }, completion: nil)
         print(randomNumber)

        enemyArray.append(randomNumber)

    }
}
```

//New Code

```
    func beginGame(){

    var level = 5

    for _ in 1...level {
        self.randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)) + 1
        let originalColor:UIColor = self.view.viewWithTag(randomNumber)!.backgroundColor!
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 4, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {


            self.view.viewWithTag(self.randomNumber)!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
              self.view.viewWithTag(self.randomNumber)!.backgroundColor = originalColor

            print("gary")


            }, completion: nil)

         print(randomNumber)

        enemyArray.append(randomNumber)

    }




}
```

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the delay in the animateWithDuration method so that the four different animations don't fire at the same time?

Comment: Yes I have. I've played with both values.

Comment: You are essentially doing all of the animations at the same time. The for loop queue up all of the animations and then they all run concurrently. Increase the delay for each one so it waits until the previous is done.

Comment: I have increased delay. It makes everything go slower but like you said, they all seem to go at same time.

Comment: You are also resetting each view's background color before the changed color has a chance to take affect.

Comment: I just want the view to blink.

Comment: Animate the resetting of the background color in the `completion` block of the first animation.

Comment: Essentially I want one view to randomly blink and then about a second later have another view randomly blink.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to what people are telling you. If you use a for loop and create multiple animations that all have a delay value of 0, they will all run at the same time. Don't do that.

Instead, use code more like this:

```
let pauseBetweenAnimations = 1.0
for step in 1...level {
  self.randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)) + 1
  let originalColor:UIColor = 
    self.view.viewWithTag(randomNumber)!.backgroundColor!
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: (step - 1) * pauseBetweenAnimations, 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, 
    animations:
    //the rest of your code goes here...
```

That will make each subsequent animation start 1 second after the previous one. If 1 second is too long, change the value of pauseBetweenAnimations.

Comment: I'm sorry but that code didn't work either. It doesn't like the step -1.  Could you add more to the function so I can just copy and paste to see if it will work logically? I also have adjusted delay in the past and that didn't work either.

Comment: You probably need to add a type cast to convert (step-1) to a Double. Try this: ` UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: Double(step - 1) * pauseBetweenAnimations

Comment: I think it likes Int's not double from previous tries. Does step even have a numerical value?

Comment: Delay is supposed to be a Double. Based on your code I'm assuming that step is an Int. What is the type of `level`?

Comment: Increasing the delay does not work. I still run into the same problem. That is what your code above is doing. I've already tried that.

Comment: Edit your post to show the new code you are trying. (At the bottom. Don't change your original code). What I have posted will absolutely, positively work. I've done things just like that one multiple occasions. You must be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: That new code is using a fixed delay, and won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't understand why? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because that is how you do what you want to do. I give up.